# Ionic 1 : iOS Black Screen on lauch app

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, ionic-framework

I have an app built in Ionic 1. It works very well on Chrome and Android but on my iOS simulator and my iPhone 6 Plus device I'm always getting stuck after the SplashScreen. The only way to get it to continue is to press the home button and re-open the app. But I can't publish my app with this bug. I have already tried everything I found on the internet.

Comment: any build errors in terminal while building?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated my Content-Security-Policy in my HTML by adding : `gap://ready file://*`

And then it worked fine on all platforms.